# How to display human readable text below the barcode using barby gem in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Barby gem in rails project to display barcode. I am able to display barcode , However its not displaying human readable text. How do I display the text below the barcode? Any help is much appreciated.

Code:

```
 def generate_barcode(value)
    barcode = Barby::Code128B.new(value)
    barcode.to_svg(xdim:1, height:40).html_safe
 end
```

View:

```
<%= generate_barcode(value) %>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be exposed as a route where you can `image_tag(...)` it back in? Inline SVG can be kind of a mess.

Comment: I'm not sure if that library lets to include text as part of the image, but just glancing at the documentation I *think* you can use `barcode.to_s` to print it out as a regular string?

Comment: barcode.to_s worked! thanks